# Where are my missing disk？

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, disk, disk-usage

There is 78GB what I see in the tool "**Disk**", the 78GB is mounted at `/home`. But in "**Disk Usage**" there is only 20GB total in my ubuntu, which is mounted at `Filesystem Root`.
I am sure that I take 100GB to Ubuntu from my hard disk. 
So where is my lost 78GB of space? Please help me. Many thanks!
[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiKZj.png)

There is another picture.[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/264Fu.png)

Comment: The recommended minimum root partition size for Ubuntu is 25 GB. 20 GB is not sufficient for `/`

Answer (score 0):

The partition 9 seems to be 78GB. If you click on that partition you should see where is mounted. As I understand your root partition si 20GB and /home partition is 78GB.

Comment: Yes, it is mounted at /home. But just like what I show, the left of the picture tells me that the home is 20GB in total. And when I start Ubuntu, it warns me the storage is 900Mb free.

Comment: @CHINEW The warning is because the / (root) is indeed almost full. When you have a single partition the space is shared for OS, programs and user files and settings. With a separated /home partition this one is used ONLY for personal files and settings. Again, giving only 20GB to root was a bad decision as it's almost full. The rest of the partitioning is also a mess: Ubuntu now uses a swapfile, no swap partition needed; you have an additional 512MB FAT partition probably not in use because you already have an ESP in the beginning of the drive, only one per system is needed.